# ASP.NET Framework - How to resolve SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

In ASP.NET Framework 4.8, I am to consume a `POST` request using `HttpClient`.

I get this error:

> System.AggregateException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=One or more errors occurred.
> Source=mscorlib
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
> at Service.SingleTransferRequest(String TransRef, String TransactionDate, String DebitAccount, String CreditAccount, String Currency, Decimal Amount, String Narration, String oldTransRef, String PayerAccountNumber, String PayerLocation, String PayerName)
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack
>
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(System.IAsyncResult)
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult)
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> Inner Exception 2:
> WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> Inner Exception 3:
> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> Inner Exception 4:
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

and it highlights this line of code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionUrl, content).Result;
```

Kindly help resolve it.

NOTE: I don't want to use async Task.

`web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PostTransactionUrl" value="https://myapi.com/PostEntries"/>
</appSettings>
```

Service Layer:

```
private string apiBaseSingleTransactionUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PostTransactionUrl"];

[WebMethod]
public SingleTransferResponse SingleTransferRequest(String TransRef, String TransactionDate, String DebitAccount, String CreditAccount, String Currency, decimal Amount, String Narration, String oldTransRef, string PayerAccountNumber, string PayerLocation, string PayerName)
{
    ControlModel control = new ControlModel();

    control = GetControl();

    bool isDD = false;

    Account acct = null;

    SingleTransferResponse resp = new SingleTransferResponse();
    String IsReversed = String.Empty;
    decimal tranID = 0;
    resp.Amount = Amount;
    int? OverrideId = null;

    try
    {
        String forcePost = String.Empty;
        String ErrorText = String.Empty;

        if (isDD == false)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bypass SSL/TLS certificate validation for your API endpoint
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

                // Create an instance of HttpClient
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Build the request object
                    SingleTransferRequestDto requestDto = new SingleTransferRequestDto
                    {
                        Transactions = new List<Transaction>
                    {
                        new Transaction
                        {
                            AccountNumber = DebitAccount,
                            TransactionAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Amount),
                            Narration = Narration,
                            TransactionMode = 0, // Assuming Debit
                            IsCharge = false
                        },
                        new Transaction
                        {
                            AccountNumber = CreditAccount,
                            TransactionAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Amount),
                            Narration = Narration,
                            TransactionMode = 1, // Assuming Credit
                            IsCharge = false
                        }
                    },
                        OriginReferenceNumber = TransRef,
                        AllowCustomDescription = true,
                        Currency = Currency
                    };

                    // Serialize the request DTO to JSON
                    string jsonRequest = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(requestDto);

                    // Create a StringContent from the JSON request
                    var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    // Make the POST request to the API endpoint
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(apiBaseSingleTransactionUrl, content).Result;

                    // Check if the request was successful
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Deserialize the API response
                        string jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleTransferResponseDto>(jsonResponse);

                        // Parse the responseXml to extract data
                        //var responseXml = XElement.Parse(apiResponse.payload.responseXml);

                        if (apiResponse.payload.responseStatus == "SUCCESS")
                        {
                            // Parse the XML response
                            XElement root = XElement.Parse(apiResponse.payload.responseXml);

                            // Define the namespaces used in your XML
                            XNamespace soapNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
                            XNamespace fcubsNamespace = "http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSIFService";

                            // Use XNamespace and XName to access elements with colons
                            var extSysAccDetailsElement = root.Element(soapNamespace + "Body")

                                .Element(fcubsNamespace + "CREATEEXTACCENTRIES_FSFS_RES")

                                .Element(fcubsNamespace + "FCUBS_BODY")

                                .Element(fcubsNamespace + "Ext-Sys-Acc-Master-Full")

                                .Element(fcubsNamespace + "Ext-Sys-Acc-Details");

                            if (extSysAccDetailsElement != null)
                            {
                                var trndtElement = extSysAccDetailsElement.Element(fcubsNamespace + "TRNDT");

                                var lcyamountElement = extSysAccDetailsElement.Element(fcubsNamespace + "LCYAMOUNT");

                                if (trndtElement != null && lcyamountElement != null)
                                {
                                    var trndt = trndtElement.Value;
                                    var lcyamount = lcyamountElement.Value;

                                    resp.TransRef = TransRef;
                                    resp.TransactionDate = trndt;
                                    resp.Amount = decimal.Parse(lcyamount);
                                    resp.ResponseCode = "00";
                                    resp.ResponseText = "SUCCESS";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Handle the case where the elements are missing in Ext-Sys-Acc-Details
                                    resp.ResponseCode = "8005";
                                    resp.ResponseText = "Required elements not found in Ext-Sys-Acc-Details";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Handle the case where Ext-Sys-Acc-Details is missing
                                resp.ResponseCode = "8006";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resp.ResponseCode = "7800";
                            resp.ResponseText = "INVALID TRANS REF";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resp.ResponseText = "API Request Failed";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.WriteLog(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            }

            return resp;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(ex);
    }

    return resp;
}
```